# Restrictions.sqlRestriction exception Hibernate with Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I have an issue executing Criteria with Restriction criterion using hibernate and Oracle db.

The simplified criteria is:
`criteria1.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("{pets}.givenName = 'Wayne')"));`

This gives me NullPointerExceltion. I understand that I need to put setEscapeProcessing(false) in order to ignore brackets '{}' in {pets}, but i don't know how to do that because I am using Criteria.

I will be glad if someone can help me.

This is the exception generated:

```
1 ERROR http-8080-2 lists.SimplePagingList - Could not load current list
```

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.getNumRows(T4C8Oall.java:876)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:831)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1039)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:850)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1134)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3339)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3384)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:186)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1787)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:674)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2213)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2104)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2099)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1569)
    at org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:283)

Answer (score 0):

I manage to fix the issue.

First issue was that instead {pets} i had to use just {alias}.

Second issue was that I was creating the criteria with:

```
Criteria criteria1 = criteriaOrg.**createAlias**(...)
```

I have changed it to:

```
Criteria criteria1 = criteriaOrg.**createCriteria**(...)
```